# Is there a way I can creates loops over a dataframe with R?

Tags: r, dataframe, data-science

I am trying to create a loop that will apply a smoothing function to all my variables of interest. The data set I am using is the aemet dataset in R and the focus is on temperature. to apply the smoothing on the 10th column I run the following codes which worked fine.

```
library(fda)
library(fda.usc)
data(aemet,package = "fda.usc")
tt = aemet$temp$argvals
temp = as.data.frame(aemet$temp$data,row.names=F)
range.tt = aemet$temp$rangeval
inv.temp = data.frame(t(aemet$temp$data)) # 365 x 73 matrix
names(inv.temp) = aemet$df$name # Oviedo is the 10th column of inv.temp
ovibasis5 = create.fourier.basis(rangeval = range(tt),nbasis = 5)
ovifourier5.fd = smooth.basis(argvals = tt, y = inv.temp[,i],fdParobj = ovibasis5)$fd
ovi5 = eval.fd(tt,ovifourier5.fd)
ovi5
```

Next, I want to apply the smoothing to all the 73 columns in the dataset so I used the loop function as follows

```
for(i in 1: inv.temp){
ovibasis5 = create.fourier.basis(rangeval = range(tt),nbasis = 5)
ovifourier5.fd = smooth.basis(argvals = tt, y = inv.temp[,i],fdParobj = ovibasis5)$fd
ovi5[,i] = eval.fd(tt,ovifourier5.fd)
}
ovi5
```

but then I get this error message
"Error in 1:inv.temp : NA/NaN argument
In addition: Warning message:
In 1:inv.temp : numerical expression has 73 elements: only the first used
>
> ovi5"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You could try `seq_len(ncol(inv.temp))` instead of `1:inv.temp`.

Comment: Hi. It would be great if you coudl share: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Apart from that, your `inv-temp` is a data frame with columns and rows whereas the for loop expects a uni-dimensional vector, i.e. the number of columns of that data frame.

Comment: @MartinGal ... or slightly more succinctly, `seq_along(inv.temp)`.

Comment: @r2evans Of course you're right. I simply can't keep in mind if this sequences along the columns or the rows... Perhaps now I can...

Comment: @MartinGal I get the same error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take `ovibasis5` outside the loop as it is constant and doesn't change it's value in the loop. Initialise the output matrix (`ovi5`) with same number of rows and columns as `inv.temp`.

```
library(fda)
library(fda.usc)

ovibasis5 = create.fourier.basis(rangeval = range(tt),nbasis = 5)
ovi5 <- matrix(nrow = nrow(inv.temp), ncol = ncol(inv.temp))

for(i in seq_along(inv.temp)){
  ovifourier5.fd = smooth.basis(argvals = tt, y = inv.temp[,i],fdParobj = ovibasis5)$fd
  ovi5[,i] = eval.fd(tt,ovifourier5.fd)
}
#Sample output
ovi5[1:5, 1:5]

#         [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]
#[1,] 10.99621 9.378179 7.839638 4.930860 5.370917
#[2,] 10.97734 9.360540 7.827852 4.913171 5.365705
#[3,] 10.95973 9.344325 7.817700 4.897670 5.362975
#[4,] 10.94339 9.329520 7.809155 4.884335 5.362678
#[5,] 10.92829 9.316107 7.802192 4.873138 5.364765

#complete output 
ovi5
```

Comment: Thank you for the eleboration. It worked!